# How can I get record ID on Edit view layout?

Tags: cakephp, view

How can I get ID of current record, on Edit view layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load the Model in question and access it that way from within the view (which, in my opinion, is an awful idea) or you can 'set' it within your controller action:

```
// In the controller action that renders the view
$this->set('current_id',$this->ModelName->id);

// Access it this way in the view/layout:
<?php echo $current_id; ?>
```

You could also grab the current record ID using ajax, but that doesn't sound like something that would benefit you here.

Good luck

Answer (score 2):

Use $this->data['ModelName']['id'] in the view

Answer (score 0):

Since 2.3, as long as you have $this->Form->hidden('fieldname'); you can reliably use $this->Form->value('ModelName.fieldname') for the value of a field in the form. When the view is rendered, just as html input tags get a value based on the model used in the controller and referenced in the $this->Form-create('ModelName'), when rendering the $this->Form->value('ModelName.fieldname') has a value.

In the controller, $this->request->data['ModelName'] is set to an array of the Model's data in CakePhp, where ['id'] points to the value of the id field.

```
$this->Form->create('ModelName');
$this->Form->input('id');
$this->Form->end();
```

Corresponds to controller logic where $this->request->data['ModelName'] gets an associative array with at least "id" => some id value depending on the data read from the database.

Note that when you use $this->Form->value() to retrieve form data, it will work when the screen is initially rendered by the controller, but may fail when the screen is rendered again because a model validation rule that used a function in the model definition failed.

To make sure that the $this->Form->value() is reliable with more rigorous model validation logic, use $this->Form->hidden('fieldName'); to hold the data in $this->request->data['ModelName'] throughout multiple model validation iterations.